# node js find problem with special characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i build a simple search form with onchange event but when i put in search input something like / or ' or alert( it returning my error and this is my backend code:

```
const searchAds = async (req, res, next) => {
  const search = req.params.search;

  let ads;
  try {
    ads = await Ad.find({ "title": { $regex: '.*' + search,$options:'i' + '.*' }});
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Searching ads failed, please try again later.',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
  const pageSize = 20;
  const pager = paginate(ads.length, page, pageSize);
  const pageOfItems = ads.map(ad => ad.toObject({ getters: true })).slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);

  return res.json({ pager, pageOfItems });
};
```

whats the best way to avoid this? Also is this correct way for find method?

Comment: Showing the error might be helpful

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'totalItems' of undefined
Is there any way to escape all special characters? I tryed package https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-string-regexp but it didnt solve problem

Comment: You can try simple [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your search variable in encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent()?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: also i tried this and i still have problems with ? # % &

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex-escape to escape your search parameter.

```
var escape = require("regex-escape");
...
ads = await Ad.find({ "title": { $regex: '.*' + escape(search), $options:'i' + '.*' }});
```

Comment: thanks alot, it solve a half of problem but i still get the error when type / or ? is there anyway to add custom characters that need to be skipped? but it return error when first character in input is / or ? and with #